# Jackson Parser for recursively parsing unknown input structure

Tags: java, json, parsing, recursion, jackson

I'm trying to parse recursively json input structure in java like the format below and trying to rewrite the same structure in another json.

Meanwhile I need to validate each & every json key/values while parsing.

{"Verbs":[{
    "aaaa":"30d", "type":"ed", "rel":1.0, "id":"80", "spoken":"en", "ct":"on", "sps":null
},{
    "aaaa":"31", "type":"cc", "rel":3.0, "id":"10", "spoken":"en", "ct":"off", "sps":null
},{
    "aaaa":"81", "type":"nn", "rel":3.0, "id":"60", "spoken":"en", "ct":"on", "sps":null
}]}

Please advice how I can use Jackson parser JsonToken enums for reading and writing unknown json content.

Comment: You can use JSON Schema to validate your JSON. What do you mean by transforming exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) to validate your inputs.

Find the documentation for the data format, but from what I can read here, the schema would be something like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "Verbs" ],
    "properties": {
        "Verbs": { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/verb" } }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "verb": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [ "aaaa", "type", "rel", "id", "spoken", "ct", "sps" ],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "aaaa": { "type": "string" },
                "type": { "type": "string" },
                "rel": { "type": "number" },
                "id": { "type": "string", "pattern": "^[0-9]+$" },
                "spoken": { "type": "string" },
                "ct": { "enum": [ "on", "off" ] },
                "sps": { "enum": [ null ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you use Jackson, you can use [this library](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) which can validate your data for you.

Transforming your JSON after that can be done by creating a new `JsonNode`, for instance.

Comment: Json input data structure is not known till parsing so I can't create schema without knowing data structure

Comment: You mean not known at all? Don't you even have an idea of the possible structures implied?